# I get a 500 query error in my Node.js web app on Bluemix with Cloudant Lite service

Tags: node.js, error-handling, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am getting the following error in my Node.js console window when I execute a certain function accessing my Cloudant database from the associated web application:

> "Error: You've exceeded your current limit of 5 requests per second for query class".

I get this corresponding error in my Chrome web browser:

> "MethodHubFrontend-1.1.0.js:32 POST http://cognitivehub.w3ibm.mybluemix.net/api/export/archive 500 (Internal Server Error)".

Our application is running on Bluemix Dedicated (CIO) with the Cloudant Lite service.  What is causing these errors?  Is it because we are exceeding the 5 queries per second throughput limitation in Cloudant Lite?

Is there an option in Cloudant Standard, other than the one that provides 50 queries per second, which we could use?

How should we be handling the error in our Node.js server so it returns a 3xx error code instead of the 500 error code?

Answer (score 3):

> What is causing these errors? Is it because we are exceeding the 5 queries per second throughput limitation in Cloudant Lite?

Yes, you are correct. You will need to upgrade to the Standard plan to raise the rate limit. Take a look at the details in the *Account* tab in the Cloudant web console for more information.

> Is there an option in Cloudant Standard, other than the one that provides 50 queries per second, which we could use?

There are several levels, as listed in the *Accounts* > *Capacity* tab.

> Also, how should we be handling the error in our Node.js server so it returns a 3xx error code instead of the 500 error code?

Cloudant should return HTTP code 429 (Too Many Requests). Your app can respond to this error condition in two ways - fail or re-send the request.

Comment: I am experiencing the same error and have a 5 second wait time in between each request I make to the Cloudant Service.  I think something is wrong with the service.

Answer (score -1):

I am experiencing the same error the past few days.  Here is the code I am using. I think the problem is related to nodejs asynchronous nature and not properly using callbacks so that the code / requests get sent synchronously versus unintended asynchronously all at the same time.

> Error: You've exceeded your current limit of 5 requests per second for query class

I wait 1 second wait time in between each request I make to the Cloudant Service.  I think something is wrong with the service.

```
// Used to add sleep time between calls to cloudant
var sleep = require('sleep'); 
const winston = require('winston')
var action_result = null
winston.level = 'debug';
var dbCredentials = {
    dbName: 'testdb'
};
var feed = 1;
//Intialize DB for putting records in Cloudant.
dbCredentials.url = "https://replace with your URL-bluemix:replacewith your URL-bluemix.cloudant.com";
cloudant = require('cloudant')(dbCredentials.url);

// check if DB exists if not create a  testdb database
cloudant.db.create(dbCredentials.dbName, function(err, data) {
winston.log("debug","create a test database Error:", err);
winston.log("debug","create a test database Data:", data);      
});

dbnames = cloudant.db.use(dbCredentials.dbName);
winston.log("debug","Creating a record in  database %s" , dbCredentials.dbName);

//  Insert a one second timeout delay to not exceed 5 queries every 1 second in Cloudant API
winston.log("debug","Reproduce timeout error First SLEEP 5 minutes---------------  FIND Time is %d ", new Date().getTime() / 1000 );
sleep.sleep(1);
//Check if the asset action already exists.
dbnames.find({selector:{feed:feed }}, function(er, action_result) {
sleep.sleep(5);
    if (er) {
        winston.log("debug",'[db.find]  Error Message %s', er.message);
throw er;
     }
});
    if ( action_result !== null) {
    winston.log("debug",'Reproduce timeout error found results %d documents.', action_result.docs.length);
    return action_result;
 }else{
        winston.log("debug",'Reproduce timeout error before loop');
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            winston.log("debug","Reproduce timeout error SLEEP item %d ---------------  FIND Time is %d " ,i,  new Date().getTime() / 1000 );
            sleep.sleep(1);
            dbnames.insert(docData (i, new Date().getTime() / 1000),     function(err, body, header) {
                    if (err) {
                        return winston.log("debug",'[db.insert] ', err.message);
                    }       
                    winston.log("debug",'You have inserted the doc.');
                    expert_exists = false;
                });
        }; //End Loop
}; //End Else

function docData (number, timestring) {
    var responseData = {
            feed : number,
            time : timestring,
    };   
    return responseData;  
}
```